# Creating an unknown amount of threads in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Hi for a program I'm working on I need to complete a task using an variable amount of threads.  The class Mythread that extends Thread is stored within another class X I have created.

What's supposed to happen is when I call X it passes a parameter n, that specifies the maximum amount of threads that can be used.  I'm not sure how to go about creating n amount of threads because everything I've read online states that a thread must be called explicitly like

```
Thread thread1 = new Mythread();
```

I tried:

```
while (0 >= n)
  {Thread thread1 = new Mythread(); n--;}
```

but this didn't work. Any ideas on how to go about doing this? Sorry if my problem is a little vague, it's for school and I want to learn the material on my own then post the bulk of the project.  If there's any other information you need or clarification feel free to ask.

Comment: `0 >= n` is false initially, so the loop never runs.

Comment: 0 >= n - another reason why conditions of the form (constant comparator variable) are undesirable.  Should be (n>=0), which everyone can read without making a mental reversal.  But better yet, this should be a `for` construct - `for(int xa=0; xa<n; xa++)`.

Answer (score 7):

Normally what you would do is create a pooled Executor with a bounded number of threads, and use a loop or some other mechanism to pass in an arbitrary number of Callable tasks:

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  exec.submit(new MyCallable());
}
```

Comment: Since he mentioned it's homework, he most likely needs to create the threads by hand for this project, and at some future date will learn about existing threadpool implementations.

Comment: That is possible, just like it is possible that his professor/book is teaching outdated concepts and he needs to learn the new, better way somehow.

Comment: Agree. And Executors.newFixedThreadPool()  returns ThreadPoolExecutor instance which can be called getCompletedTaskCount() and getActiveCount() to monitor the pool status.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you need a variable number of variables, try an array.  Then you'll have:

```
for( i = 0; i < n; ++i )
    threadarray[i] = new Mythread();
```

Your immediate problem was that you never started your loop, since you had the condition backwards.  But saving the threads in an array is a good idea to make sure they don't get garbage collected.

Comment: Threads will not normally be garbage collected, since they are considered "top level" objects by the garbage collector (well, I think daemon threads are, but not user threads, but couldn't find it in the docs). I would also use a Collection, such as LinkedList, so you don't need to much around with allocating the right size and managing the storage of the array.

Comment: @John: Doesn't a Thread have to be started explicitly?  If so, they have to remain reachable so he can iterate through and start them.  And I definitely would have recommended a collection if the number wasn't known a-priori, but it is, so an array is the simplest tool which gets the job done.

Comment: make sure start(); is called, too

Answer (score 0):

Probably, what you are missing is that you have to call `start()` on a `Thread` to start it.

But beyond that, you probably should not be declaring a subclass of `Thread`.  Better alternatives are:

- Put your thread's mainline code in the `run()` method of a class that implements the `Runnable` interface, and instantiate `Thread` objects with an instance of your class as a parameter; e.g.

  ```
  new Thread(new MyRunnable(...)).start();
  ```
- Use an `ExecutorService` as described by @John Gaughan's answer.
- Use some other kind of thread pool.

Bounded thread pools are a good idea if you have a potentially unbounded number of tasks to perform, and they aren't strictly required to run in parallel.  (Java tends to use lots of resources and perform poorly if you create huge numbers of Threads.)

(Creating subclasses of `Thread` is generally frowned on these days because it leads to mistakes like overriding the `Thread.start()` method incorrectly, and so on.  Unfortunately, there are lots of old tutorials and examples floating around that extend `Thread`.)

Comment: I agree with not subclassing Thread, if you are going the route of managing threads directly. Always implement Runnable. It decouples thread management from the task being executed, and makes it much more difficult to write bugs.